# Best Practice to handle form submission status pages reload

Tags: django, django-forms, user-experience

I have a django email form that posts to a URL which in turn redirects to another and renders a success/failure html.

I am using the Django Messaging framework to display success/failure messages on the form submission status.

All this works except when the user reloads the status page, the message is popped and I get a blank screen.

I am wondering what the correct treatment for this scenario is.
Should I redirect to homepage if there are no messages, or maybe have a generic two-liner as a fail-safe?

PS: If this is not an appropriate question on SO, kindly recommend an alternate site for me to ask this question, I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

The messages displayed using the Django messages framework are **displayed once in the subsequent request**. If you refresh the page or go to another page, the message will disappear. This is the intended behaviour of using messages.

As per Django messaging framework [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/messages/#module-django.contrib.messages):

> Quite commonly in web applications, you need to display a one-time
>   notification message (also known as **“flash message”**) to the user after
>   processing a form or some other types of user input.
>
> The messages framework allows you to temporarily store messages in one
>   request and retrieve them for display in a subsequent request (usually
>   the next one).

To solve your issue, you can send the success or failure as a parameter in the url parameters and then display the message in the template according to its value. Then, when the user refreshes the page, the message text will still be displayed in the template.

Comment: Thanks. Although this did occur to me, my question more broadly is what is the best practice? Is this the best practice?

Comment: Depends on different use cases. If you want to display the error message each time the user refreshes, you would not be able to use messages. You will have to pass the parameters in your url and then  display the message according to its value. Another option(not recommended) is Django sessions where you can set the message in the session and then  use it to get the error message everytime.